# How to apply textures to a custom geometry

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl

I'm a very green newb attempting to understand textures and geometries. The code below should render triangle and apply an image as a texture. However, I get the following error:

```
.WebGLRenderingContext: GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : glDrawElements: attempt to access out of range vertices in attribute 0
```

Any Ideas?

```
var scene = new THREE.Scene(),
    geometry = new THREE.Geometry();
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, .1, 1000);
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();

geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(-1, -1, 0));
geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(-1, 1, 0));
geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(1, -1, 0));

geometry.faces.push( new THREE.Face3(0, 2, 1)); 

geometry.faceVertexUvs[ 0 ].push(
    THREE.Vector2( 0, 1),
    THREE.Vector2( 1, 1),
    THREE.Vector2( 1, 0)
);


geometry.computeCentroids();
geometry.computeFaceNormals();
geometry.computeVertexNormals();

var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    //color: 0xFF0000, 
    //wireframe: true,
    map : THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('cheese2.231104333_std.jpg')
});

var shape = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
shape.doubleSided = true;
shape.overdraw = true;

scene.add(shape);

camera.position.z = 10;
renderer.setClearColorHex(0x00000, 1);
renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

renderer.render(scene, camera);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You need to push an `array` in the following code. Make sure the UVs map correctly to your vertices.

   `geometry.faceVertexUvs[ 0 ].push( [ new THREE.Vector2( 1, 0 ), new THREE.Vector2( 1, 1 ), new THREE.Vector2( 0, 1 ) ] );`
2. `mesh.doubleSided` has been replaced with `material.side = THREE.DoubleSide`. Be sure to learn from the official three.js examples, and avoid old examples from the net.
3. Texture loading is asynchronous and you are rendering only once, likely before the texture loads. Add an animation loop.

three.js r.60

Comment: I was missing the array bit. now i'm recieving this strange error:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'x' of undefined

Comment: See if the typo correction above solves your problem. If not, then provide a live example of your code.

Comment: That did it! Now i need to sort out how to get the texture to span multiple faces. Studying PlanneGeometry is a bit confusing to me.

Comment: A picture is worth a thousand words. See http://threejs.org/examples/misc_uv_tests.html.

Comment: Thanks for that. It helped me discover a much easier way of accomplishing my goal. I'm attempting to build 3d plane. Instead of creating a custom geometry, i simply used a PlaneGeometry and iterated though the vertices to change the z index.

Comment: WestLangley, i had the same problem, but the texture doesn't load. How do i add an Animation Loop?

Comment: @ThiagoPonte If you have a question, you need to make a new post. But first, search the posts on this site and study the three.js examples.